# Is there a less horrible way to write this code still compatible with WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have this horrible code I have been trying to improve without success over WCF service.

On server side I have this contract:

```
[ServiceContract]    
public interface IOhmioService
{
    [OperationContract]        
    IEnumerable<Enumerador> GetEnumerador(string sClassType);
}
```

And this implementation **(This is the code I'm trying to improve, especially that awful switch)**:

```
public IEnumerable<Enumerador> GetEnumerador(string sClassType)
    {
      
        IEnumerador _obj;
        switch (sClassType)
        {
            case "Clients":
                _obj = new Clientes();
                break;
            case "Vendors":
                _obj = new Vendedores();
                break;
            default:
                _obj = new Clientes();
                break;
        }
        return _obj.Enumerar();
       
    }
```

And call this method from client like this:

```
Clients = this.serviceClient.GetEnumerador("Clientes");
```

The idea is this: I have a few class in which I implement this interface:

```
public class Enumerador
{
    public int ID{ get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
}

public interface IEnumerador
{
    IEnumerable<Enumerador> Enumerar();
}
```

And what I want is that the client can decide which object it wishes to Enumerate. The problem is that I can't send the Type directly because it is not serializable so it won't pass WCF service.

So how can I create a service method in which the client can decide the object to enumerate (The returned type is always Enumerador). I know that I can't send data without specify the type on WCF because SOAP don't support it, but I just need a way to tell the server which object to create!

Comment: From a usability point of view, I do think that having separate methods for GetClientes() and GetVendedores() exposed via the web service API makes things a lot clearer and user friendly, rather than calling a single method passing in a string representing what the caller wants. You could still have the implementation of these individual methods call a generic method to return an IEnumerable<Enumerador>, and have Clientes and Vendedores derive from Enumerador to keep things cleaner on the server side.

Comment: since the purpose of method 'GetEnumerador' is just creating new object   of class, why can't we put this at client side?

Comment: Thanks @yyou. Just because client knows nothing about database objects, and the classes that implement Enumerador a derived from Entity Framework on DataLayer.

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface and have all the classes i.e. Clientes, Vendedores implement it. and then pass the Interfact to the method instead of the string. and create an object and do your coding. Please find the code below:

```
public interface ISample
{
    IList<string> GetData();
}

public class Sample1 :ISample
{
    public IList<string> GetData()
    {
        IList<string> names = new List<string>();
        names.Add("Tom");
        names.Add("Peter");
        return names;
    }
}
public class Sample2 : ISample
{
    public IList<string> GetData()
    {
        IList<string> names = new List<string>();
        names.Add("Human");
        names.Add("Immortal");
        return names;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c1 = new CalledClass();
        IList<string> data = c1.GetData(new Sample2());
        foreach (var name in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Immortal. Actually my code, it's pretty close to what you wrote. I create an interface (IEnumerador) and i implemment it on both Clients and Vendors Class. Now the problem is that i need to create a method that returns a collection of IENumerador that could come from Clients OR Vendors deppending on client call. If WCF wasn't in between i could do this:  public IEnumerable<Enumerador> GetEnumerador(Type type) but i won't work with WCF.